# Duplication is happening

Tags: c#, arraylist, listbox

```
     public void DisplayAlbum(int thisAlbum )
      {
        if (Albums[thisAlbum] != null)

        {
            albumIDtextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].AlbumID.ToString();
            albumNametextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].AlbumName.ToString();
            releaseDatetextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].ReleaseDate;
            albumLabeltextBox.Text = Albums[thisAlbum].Label.ToString();
        }
       }
```

I do not know what this his happening I have a view button which displays the list of items eg albums but I have create a clear button which clears all the text boxs and listbox and when i go back to view button instead of just showing 3 albums its shows 6 and this happens everything and number of albums get 2x bigger each time i click view button after clearing all textboxes.

this is my clear button code

```
    private void clearAllbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        trackListbox.DataSource = null;
        trackListbox.Items.Clear();
        albumCoverBox.Image = Properties.Resources.nocover;

        AmazonlinkwebBrowser.Navigate("about:blank");


        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                c.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `clear` method (or something) is creating boxes rather than modifying them. The above code isn't the cause

Comment: Updated with clear button code

Comment: Without the clear method the data still gets duplicated

Comment: What is the type definition of `Albums`, and how do you add items to it, and in which method?

Comment: Album is class and it has list and it has constructor to pass data into the list

Comment: Could you share the code for `Albums` class and how you populate `trackListBox`

Comment: Is there a way to stop repeating list data i think i know the problem i need some kind of validation of some sort to stop view button creating same data